# NoMethodError: undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a big problem with my application. My site is on AWS and this morning I do a cap production deploy to add the new version online. But my url don't work anymore and that is a very very big problem for me so I put my question here...

I use `Ruby on Rails EC2 S3` and `shrine` for my application and when I want to do a `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate` I have the error :

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-partitions-1.70.0/lib/aws-partitions/endpoint_provider.rb:82:in `block in partition_matching_region'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-partitions-1.70.0/lib/aws-partitions/endpoint_provider.rb:81:in `each'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-partitions-1.70.0/lib/aws-partitions/endpoint_provider.rb:81:in `find'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-partitions-1.70.0/lib/aws-partitions/endpoint_provider.rb:81:in `partition_matching_region'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-partitions-1.70.0/lib/aws-partitions/endpoint_provider.rb:70:in `get_partition'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-partitions-1.70.0/lib/aws-partitions/endpoint_provider.rb:23:in `signing_region'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-partitions-1.70.0/lib/aws-partitions/endpoint_provider.rb:99:in `signing_region'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.8.2/lib/aws-sdk-s3/plugins/s3_signer.rb:20:in `block in <class:S3Signer>'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.17.0/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:70:in `call'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.17.0/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:205:in `block in resolve_defaults'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.17.0/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:57:in `each'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.17.0/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:57:in `each'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.17.0/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:204:in `resolve_defaults'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.17.0/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:200:in `value_at'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.17.0/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:189:in `block in resolve'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.17.0/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:189:in `resolve'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.17.0/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:177:in `apply_defaults'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.17.0/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:150:in `build!'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.17.0/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:62:in `build_config'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.17.0/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:19:in `initialize'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.8.2/lib/aws-sdk-s3/client.rb:197:in `initialize'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.17.0/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:99:in `new'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.8.2/lib/aws-sdk-s3/resource.rb:14:in `initialize'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/shrine-2.9.0/lib/shrine/storage/s3.rb:207:in `new'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/shrine-2.9.0/lib/shrine/storage/s3.rb:207:in `initialize'
/home/coeurcoeur/Projet/config/initializers/shrine.rb:16:in `new'
/home/coeurcoeur/Projet/config/initializers/shrine.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:655:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `load_config_initializer'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `each'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `tsort_each_child'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
/home/coeurcoeur/Projet/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:329:in `require_environment!'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:445:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@global/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What can I do to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Please add whole stacktrace to get more idea.

Comment: I edit my post. That is what you want ?

Comment: I think the problem is aws region related, make sure you have the aws region set

Comment: Ok. But where i can find it ? I look_for every where but without succeed

Comment: you just need to check your app's environment variables, `AWS_REGION` is set or not