# block in partition_matching_region': undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have cloned a repository
After cloning it.
I navigate to the folder and run the command "bundle install"
next to that i run the command "rails server" and its give me this error.

I also read some references :
[NoMethodError: undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51303095/nomethoderror-undefined-method-match-for-nilnilclass), https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/1240

Thank you for any help ..

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.3 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-partitions-1.193.0/lib/aws-partitions/endpoint_provider.rb:82:in `block in partition_matching_region': undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-partitions-1.193.0/lib/aws-partitions/endpoint_provider.rb:81:in `each'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-partitions-1.193.0/lib/aws-partitions/endpoint_provider.rb:81:in `find'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-partitions-1.193.0/lib/aws-partitions/endpoint_provider.rb:81:in `partition_matching_region'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-partitions-1.193.0/lib/aws-partitions/endpoint_provider.rb:70:in `get_partition'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-partitions-1.193.0/lib/aws-partitions/endpoint_provider.rb:23:in `signing_region'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-partitions-1.193.0/lib/aws-partitions/endpoint_provider.rb:99:in `signing_region'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.46.0/lib/aws-sdk-s3/plugins/s3_signer.rb:20:in `block in <class:S3Signer>'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.61.1/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:70:in `call'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.61.1/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:213:in `block in resolve_defaults'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.61.1/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:57:in `each'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.61.1/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:57:in `each'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.61.1/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:212:in `resolve_defaults'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.61.1/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:205:in `value_at'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.61.1/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:189:in `block in resolve'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/set.rb:324:in `each_key'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/set.rb:324:in `each'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.61.1/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:189:in `resolve'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.61.1/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:177:in `apply_defaults'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.61.1/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:150:in `build!'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.61.1/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:62:in `build_config'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.61.1/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:19:in `initialize'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.46.0/lib/aws-sdk-s3/client.rb:317:in `initialize'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.61.1/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:99:in `new'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.46.0/lib/aws-sdk-s3/resource.rb:14:in `initialize'
    from /home/mike/agingcommunity/config/initializers/aws.rb:4:in `new'
    from /home/mike/agingcommunity/config/initializers/aws.rb:4:in `<main>'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:657:in `block in load_config_initializer'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in `load_config_initializer'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:614:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `each'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
    from /home/mike/agingcommunity/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in `require_relative'
    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from config.ru:in `new'
    from config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:89:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:51:in `start'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Any help please.. Thank you

code in my GemFile

```
# Specify ruby version
ruby '2.4.6'
source 'https://rubygems.org'


#gem 'activemodel-serializers-xml'
gem "aasm"
gem 'activerecord-import', '~> 0.17.0' # Use activerecord-import to speed up bulk importation of facility records.
gem 'audited', '~> 4.5' # Log all changes to your models
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.1'
gem "aws-sdk-s3", require: false
gem 'bootsnap', require: false
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'
gem 'breadcrumbs_on_rails' # Rails 5 compatible breadcrumb gem that is popular.
gem 'cancancan' # Use cancancan for authorization.
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2' # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
# useful information about every country packaged as country objects.  It includes data from ISO 3166.
gem 'countries', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.5'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.2' # Use devise for authentication.
gem 'devise_invitable', '~> 1.7', '>= 1.7.2' # It adds support for send invitations by email
gem 'geocoder' # Provides object geocoding (by street or IP address)
# TODO: Once full support for Rails 5 is available, switch to the standard Gemfile syntax from rubygems.org.
gem 'globalize', git: 'https://github.com/globalize/globalize' # Use globalize for i18n of ActiveRecord models.
#gem 'globalize', '~> 5.1.0'
gem 'going_postal', '~> 0.1.6' # Postal code validation
gem 'haml'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7.0' # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails', '~> 0.4.7' # Direct upload to S3 requires blueimp's fileupload jquery plugin.
gem 'jquery-rails' # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.4' # Database gem for Active Record
gem 'phony', '~> 2.15', '>= 2.15.44'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0' # Use Puma as the app server
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2' # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'resque', '~> 1.22.0', require: 'resque/server' # As of 2017-02-03, Heroku insists on 1.22.0.
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0' # Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sinatra', '~> 2.0.0.beta2' # Unfortunately, I need to use the beta sinatra to get past a stupid typo.
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'twilio-ruby', '~> 5.1', '>= 5.1.2' # Use Twilio for facility ownership verification.
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0' # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.5' # TODO: consider bootstrap-will_paginate at some point.
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7' Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0' Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
### DO NOT bother with resque-scheduler. Instead, use Heroku scheduler
### which seems to be what Heroku wants.
# Use the highest resque-scheduler version compatible with resque 1.22.0.
# gem 'resque-scheduler', '~> 2.2'
gem 'awesome_print'
gem 'bindex', '~> 0.4.0'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'country_select'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'exception_handler', '~> 0.8.0.0' #Used for handling errors

group :development, :test do
  gem "letter_opener"
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  # For, "heroku local:run rails console", for example, "rails
  # console" is not inheritting the environment variables contained in
  # .env. By including dotenv-rails, I think I will be redundantly
  # loading .env in development and test.
  gem 'dotenv-rails', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.2'
  # Now that I'm doing system tests with Rails 5.1, I need Capybara and selenium-webdriver.
  # Capybara Docs: https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.14', '>= 2.14.4'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 3.4', '>= 3.4.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development do
  gem 'rb-readline'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'web-console'
end
gem 'pg_search'
```

resolve to this.. i just go to my rails console and typed this code.. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/1240#issuecomment-231866239

Comment: What's in your Gemfile?

Comment: @SebastianPalma hi .. i updated my post..

Comment: Take a look at this issue https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/1240

Comment: @SebastianPalma i think i missed out the file called .env .I'm not sure.. i seen this code in aws.rb file <%= ENV['AWS_REGION'] %>

Comment: Check if you can make this example work in the rails console https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/1240#issuecomment-231866239

Comment: @SebastianPalma thank you it resolve..